# Two different templates for user and guest? Or dynamically change the view using a client side variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, authentication, server

**Scenario 1**

I have a control panel interface (html/css), which is available to both a registered user and non-registered user. I'll use a client-side ajax just to check if there's a valid user session. If that returns a 200 (ok), I'll then have Angular hide the guest part of the interface, and show the user part. (Basically hides the login form and shows the user options section). If it returns a 400, vice versa.

**Scenario 2**

I have one control panel interface for guest, and one for a registered user. Upon requesting the control panel partial interface, I would use a server-side router/controller logic that checks for a valid user session. If it is true, response send the controlPanel-user.html. If it is false, response send the controlPanel-guest.html.

I have tried looking for proper theories for this scenario but couldn't find one specific to this situation, maybe someone here is a better Googler than I am.

Note: client side interface updates wouldn't really compromise my system, regardless whether or not the person is able to access the user-version of the html views, they would still be declined access to any API without proper server side authentication.

Comment: in a similar application i made recently i opted for 2nd approach, as it reduces clutter data from being sent to client, only the necessary data/templates are sent, but 1st option can be fine depending on use case

Comment: plus it is not always possible or better to handle user recognition/authentication in client

Comment: @Niko, did you ever settle on an implementation? Others would like to know.

Comment: @Mawg For my own requirements, I decided on scenario 1. For a light-data front end application, this shouldn't be an issue. Multiple templates would just increase the size of requests and increase server usage. Basically let the client browser do the work.

Answer (score 1):

For my own requirements, I decided on scenario 1. For a **light-data front end application**, this shouldn't be an issue. Multiple templates would just increase the amount of requests and increase server usage.

Comment: Actually, the answered is the OP, responding to my comment  which asked what he had decided on.  @Niko, Thanks  for letting us know. I think that you have to wait 2 days before you can accept your own answer, but please come back and do so, to make it clear to others seeing this question in future.